# Sitecore Forms Multi select dropdown

Tags: sitecore-forms

With Sitecore 9 Forms, is there any way of adding a multi-select drop down list?

Comment: I voted to reopen as this question seems to be very specific and direct. The user appears to be asking how to add a dropdown to the form which allows selection of multiple values from the list. (The answer is to use a ListBox which allows for setting multiple select)

Comment: I agree with that assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropdown list control does not support multiple select. Even if it did, from a UX perspective, that's not the control you would want to use. A dropdown indicates to the user that you want only one option selected. For multiple select, a form should use something like a checkbox list or a list box to indicate visually to the user that multiple answers are expected.

In this case, the most likely control you want is a [List Box](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/creating_forms/the_list_elements#_List_box).

> Use the List box element to display a list of options where a contact
>   can select any number of choices, including zero, one, or several.

It contains a **Selection Mode** property which you can use to change it to allow multiple select:

> **Selection Mode:**
>   Indicates whether only a single item or multiple items can be selected
>   from the list at one time. The options are Single or Multiple.

Alternatively, if the number of options you have is small, you could use a [Checkbox list](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/creating_forms/the_list_elements#_Checkbox_list) control. It is always intended for multiple select, but from a UX perspective you should only use this when you have a small number of items to select from.

**References:**

1. Documentation landing page: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms
2. The list elements: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/creating_forms/the_list_elements
3. Adding list items to forms: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/creating_forms/add_list_items